# Буфер обмена всегда отдает null

Tags: android

Мне нужно получить скопированную строку из буфера обмена. Я делаю это так:

```
val clipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clipData: ClipData? = clipboardManager.primaryClip
clipData?.let { textView.text = clipData.getItemAt(0).text }
```

Если я вызываю этот код в `onCreate()` или в `onResume()`, я постоянно получаю null.

Но если я вызову этот код внутри `post`:

```
textView.post {
        val clipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clipData: ClipData? = clipboardManager.primaryClip
        clipData?.let { textView.text = clipData.getItemAt(0).text }
}
```

Я получаю нужную мне строку.

Из этого я делаю вывод, что буфер обмена ждет отрисовки всех View-х на экране. Вопрос: для чего ему это нужно или может быть он ждет чего-то другого?

P.S.

Target SDK и SDK на устройстве 30+

Comment: Протестировал на реальном устройстве, код на Java, как и ожидалось в методе onCreate все работает.

Comment: А теперь сделайте тоже самое на target SDK 30. И соответственно на эмуляторе или устройстве тот же код должен работать на 30-ом SDK

Comment: Возможно данное поведение связано с добавлением в 11 андроиде Synchronized IME transitions. Попробуйте посмотреть в этом направлении.